Migrating from Shotwell
I have a lot of photos which I used to handle using Shotwell. Now that Shotwell is defunct (and won't even run on my system now, due to upgrades), what would be a good platform to migrate to? How do I migrate my already existing files?

How is Shotwell defunct? I'm not a huge fan myself (and usually use digikam) but shotwell is still in development - gitlab tags. However, wikipedia has articles comparing image viewers and organisers

Well, I've used Shotwell for several years, but now it's stopped working for me: the error message that I get is
shotwell: error while loading shared libraries: libraw.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
And there is now no libraw.so.19 in my updated version of Ubuntu. So it seems to me that shotwell is no longer being maintained, so it still seems to think it should load libraw.so.19 (because that was current when shotwell was last upgraded), and so it will now no longer run on up-to-date versions of Ubuntu.

In other words, shotwell still seems to depend on libraw.so.19, which is not available in current versions of Ubuntu.

I'm out of my comfort zone here, but I have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw.so.23 in a pretty much as installed Lubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. apt-cache show shotwell lists Version: 0.32.6-1ubuntu2 Depends : libraw23t64 (>= 0.16.0). apt-cache show 'libraw23t64' lists Version: 0.21.2-2.1build1 Provides: libraw23 (= 0.21.2-2.1build1). I don't know if that helps.

If you cannot get Shotwell reinstalled and running, e.g. by
$ sudo apt reinstall shotwell in the Terminal
then a good alternative is Darktable => www.darktable.org
I'd recommend using the AppImage to get the very latest version. Then start it from the Terminal initially, maybe create a .desktop file later.
It has a learning curve, so be prepared.
For those not so versed in image editing and related basics...
To get to grips with the basics of image editing:
https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/learn-photography-concepts.htm
Enhance your photographs, in camera, the basics:
https://visualeducation.com/photography-course/photography-composition/
